Exclude certain row from primeNg treatable sort
I am new to Angular and other FE technology.
I want to implement a primeNg treetable with 2 levels of treedata...
How can we implement sorting that only child data is sorted and toggleable rows are not involved In sorting..
Like in the image..red coloured rows should be static n not part of sorting and only child elements in blue should be sorted
Sample image
I tried to freeze rows but that does not work in treetable
